# Mask composed of multiple shapes with gradient fill in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, mask

I have a group of shapes that each have their own unique gradient fill.  I would like to use the union of those shapes to create an alpha mask for an image behind it.

In other words, I want the union of the alpha mask effects on a bitmap/image.

Things I've tried:

- union of the shapes, but I loose the fill information.
- flattening shapes to bitmap, but it seems there is no way to mask a bitmap with a bitmap (use as mask is not selectable)?

Here is a screenshot of example shapes I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: an aplha mask is a greyscale bitmap. Can you merge the shapes so you only have the mask on a white background, then copy'n'paste that into a blank alpha mask layer? This may entail a secondary temporary image/export to a raster format.

Comment: hi @Yorik. when I merge the shapes loose the unique fills for each shape. how do i prevent that from happening?

Comment: rasterize each shape first, then merge the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand the scenario:
You have several shapes, each with a different gradient fill, which you want to merge into one, keeping the unique fills, and apply that as a mask over an image. In Sketch.

Two things to keep in mind:

1. **Sketch is not a photo editing environment.** I don't know if it does alpha channel masks, but I really wouldn't want it to take on that bloat.
2. **Merged shapes are stylistically merged as well.** You can't have separate style settings between the constituent parts.

Comment: hey @plainclothes. Thanks for answering! On #1, Alpha masks are supported in Sketch for single shapes: https://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/04-shapes/4-masking.html. I simply want the union of that masking effect. On #2, thanks for some clarification.

Comment: In my experience, the alpha thing is very spotty. Does it ever work for you on raster layers?

Comment: Yeah works fine as single shape on bitmap. Thinking about I guess I could just copy the bitmap - one for each shape - apply the masks individually to each bitmap and just group the results. I'll try that. Thanks again you def got me thinking!

Comment: Glad to be a sounding board ... if I were you, I'd be spinning up Affinity Photo right now (^‿- )